# How to add 2 buttons on navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am using **Split View Controller**, which has 2 View controllers on the second view controller i am suppose add two buttons on the right side of navigation controller.
i have used the following code to add one button which works:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    [barButton setCustomView:btnShare];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButton;
```

tried this link http://osmorphis.blogspot.in/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html
but could not succeed.Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *arrRightBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIButton *btnSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnSetting setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnSetting.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
btnSetting.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
[btnSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(onSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSetting];
[arrRightBarItems addObject:barButtonItem];

UIButton *btnLib = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnLib setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"library.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnLib.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
btnLib.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
[btnLib addTarget:self action:@selector(onMyLibrary:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnLib];
[arrRightBarItems addObject:barButtonItem2];

UIButton *btnRefresh = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnRefresh setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnRefresh.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
btnRefresh.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
[btnRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(onRefreshBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnRefresh];

[arrRightBarItems addObject:barButtonItem1];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=arrRightBarItems;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[GlobalMethods buttonWithImage:@"btn_home" heighlightImageName:@"btn_home_h" buttonFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 34, 34) selectorName:@selector(buttonHomeClicked:) target:self]]];

  UIButton *tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [tempButton setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 5, 34, 34)];
  [tempButton addTarget:target action:selectorName forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [tempButton setImage:[self getImageFromResource:normalImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [tempButton setImage:[self getImageFromResource:heighlightImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  [tempButton setImage:[self getImageFromResource:@"btn_fav_h"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.buttonFavorite];
```

Answer (score 3):

create two uibarbuttonitem and add both in an array then add whole array in navigation bar

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAttachmentClicked:)];
UIBarButtonItem *sendButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:LS(@"Send") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(sendClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[addButton,sendButton];
```

try thi code

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *btnLogOut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnLogOut.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, 31);
    [btnLogOut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout_new.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLogOut addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *logOutBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnLogOut];

    UIButton *btnError = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnError.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, 31);
    [btnError setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnError addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIBarButtonItem *errorButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnError];


    NSArray *navigationBarBtnArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:errorButton,logOutBarButton, nil];



     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=navigationBarBtnArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
[rightButton release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an `UISegmentedControl` instead of a `UIButton`.

Then change the mode to "momentary" and add an action on change.

When the action is triggered, check the `selectedSegmentIndex` to know what segment was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

make a `UIView` adding as many buttons you want on it. then use

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBarbtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonsView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarbtn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use segmented control for this

```
UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray array]];
[segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample1.png"] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample2.png"] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIBarButtonItem * segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: segmentedControl];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of `UIBarButtonItem`s and pass it to

`- (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated`

method of `UINavigationItem`.