# Navigationbar button not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationitem

I have `UINavigationController`. Then i need to display navigationbar button. I used following code:

```
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:nav.view];

UIImage *info_iphone=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
UIButton *infobtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 30)];
[infobtn setBackgroundImage:info_iphone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(show_info:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn];
```

Comment: This is not the right way of creating UINavigationController. Check out the tutorials and documentation and Example is here http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/ .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379131/how-to-add-2-buttons-on-navigation-bar/15379448#15379448

Comment: NavigationBar only showing. But the button is not visible. I don't why?

Comment: @user2474320: Check if your Image is not empty.

Comment: use this line `nav.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn];` instead of `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn];`..

Comment: @ParasJoshi: I used your line also. But no use for me

Comment: @user2474320: Also, check if you are using the same image name.

Comment: @Vin: Yes using same image name

Comment: @user2474320 try this     `self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In `YourViewController`'s `-viewWillAppear` :

```
UIImage *info_iphone=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
UIButton *infobtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 30)];
[infobtn setBackgroundImage:info_iphone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(show_info:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infobtn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Comment: @user2474320: It will not work as your approach is wrong. Have you added that line in your Appdelegate.m ?

Comment: Working inside -viewWillAppear. Thanks

Comment: @user2474320: For that you should ask another Question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is with the navigation controller. You can't add it as a subview of the UIViewControllers view. I am using story boards and there you can embed your View Controllers with Navigation Controllers.

Here, your "nav" does not know that it should care about your navigationItem. Your view controller is not in his viewControllers list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding UINavigationController as subview will work for you.
Rather you can add UINavigationController as subview(or as rootviewcontroller) to UIWindow in your AppDelegate file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method as follow :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.viewController = [[[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Than in your SampleViewController's Viewdidload method add the BarButton as follow :

```
UIImage *info_iphone=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
UIButton *infobtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 30)];
[infobtn setBackgroundImage:info_iphone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(show_info:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn]];
```

Hopefully this will help you.. :)

Answer (score -1):

use this bellow code...

```
UIImage *info_iphone=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
UIButton *infobtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 30)];
[infobtn setBackgroundImage:info_iphone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(show_info:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn];
[infobtn release];
```

**UPDATE :**

use bellow code

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnSave = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
btnSave.target = self;
btnSave.action = @selector(btnSave_Clicked:);
btnSave.title = @"Save";
btnSave.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSave;
```

Comment: @user2474320 set this line `nav.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infobtn];` and post comment that it's working or not.. :)

Comment: @user2474320 use above updated code may be it will worked i hope... use `UIBarButton`