# adding button to navigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I want to have 2 right button in navigation bar. Is it possible to do and is it legitimate to app Store?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379131/how-to-add-2-buttons-on-navigation-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, It can be..

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrayOfBarButtonItems;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5.0, 25.0, 60.0, 32.0)];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]];
    [backButton setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

try this

Comment: The question asks how to add two buttons to the right side of the navigation bar. Your answer shows how to add one custom button to the left.